# Covariance of random variable and sum of random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, covariance

Consider a vector $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$, $v_k\in B$, where $B$ consists of $B_1,...,B_m$ disjoint subsets and let
\begin{align*}
 L(v_k) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad \text{, if a specific event occurs for} \quad v_k \newline
               0 \quad \text{, else} \end{cases}
\end{align*}

The probability that a specific event occurs for $v_k$ is $p_i\in(0,1)$. The probabilities $p_i$, $i\in\{1,...,m\}$, are exposed to random fluctuations $\vartheta_i$, $i\in\{1,...,m\}$. These fluctuations are realizations of random variables $\theta_i$, $i\in\{1,...,m\}$, with properties
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\theta_i]=1 \quad \text{and} \quad Cov(\theta_i,\theta_j)=\begin{cases} \sigma^2 \quad \text{, if} \quad i=j \newline \rho\sigma^2 \quad \text{, if} \quad i\neq j \end{cases}
\end{align}
Further, let
\begin{align*}
S_i:=\sum_{v_k\in B_i} L(v_k) \quad \text{and} \quad S:=\sum_{l=1}^{m} S_l
\end{align*}

Let us make the following two assumptions

\begin{align}
S_i | (\theta_1,...,\theta_m) \sim Poi(n_i p_i \theta_i)\quad ,n_i \in \mathbb{N}\newline
Cov(S_i,S_j | (\theta_1,...,\theta_m)) = 0 \quad \text{, for} \quad i \neq j, 
\end{align}

**Question 1:** How can I calculate $Cov(S_i,S)$?

**Question 2:** Following the calculation provided below by K. A. Buhr for $Cov(S_i,S)$, I now also tried to calculate $Var(S)$ by the law of total variance:
\begin{align}
Var(S)=\mathbb{E}[Var(S|\theta^*)]+Var(\mathbb{E}[S|\theta^*])
\end{align}
The first term is then just $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{l=1}^m n_l p_l \theta_l]=\sum_{l=1}^m n_l p_l$, assuming $\mathbb{E}[\theta_i]=1$.
The seond term becomes
\begin{align}
Var[\sum_{l=1}^m n_l p_l \theta_l]
=\sum_{l=1}^m Var(n_l p_l \theta_l)+\sum_{l\neq j} Cov[n_l p_l \theta_l,n_j p_j \theta_j]
=\sigma^2(\sum_{l=1}^m n_l^2 p_l^2 + \rho \sum_{l\neq j} n_l p_l n_j p_j)
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
Var(S)=\sum_{l=1}^m n_l p_l+\sigma^2(\sum_{l=1}^m n_l^2 p_l^2 + \rho \sum_{l\neq j} n_l p_l n_j p_j)
\end{align}
Are my calculations for $Var(S)$ correct?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by $Poi(n_i p_i\theta)$?   (1) What is $\theta$, (2) are the $n_i$ and $p_i$ assumed fixed constants, and (3) how do the $\theta_i$ relate to any of these parameters?

Comment: My formulation was indeed not very precice, sorry. I clarified the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have Poisson rates $n_i p_i \theta_i \geq 0$ but $E(\theta_i)=0$.  I'll assume you actually mean $E(\theta_i)=1$ (or equivalently, rates $n_i p_i (1+\theta_i)$ with $E(\theta_i)=0$).

Anyway, you should be able to apply the "[law of total covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_covariance)":
$$\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=E[\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y\mid Z)] + \mathrm{Cov}(E[X\mid Z], E[Y\mid Z])$$

Writing $\theta_\star:=(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n)$, by the conditional (lack of) correlation and marginal distributions of the $S_i$, you have:
$$\mathrm{Cov}(S_i,S\mid\theta_\star) = \mathrm{Var}(S_i\mid\theta_\star) = n_i p_i \theta_i$$
and so $E[\mathrm{Cov}(S_i,S\mid\theta_\star)] = n_i p_i$.

You also have $E[S_i\mid\theta_\star] = n_i p_i \theta_i$ and $E[S\mid\theta_\star] = \sum_j n_j p_j \theta_j$ giving:
$$\mathrm{Cov}(E[S_i\mid\theta_\star],E[S\mid\theta_\star])
= \sum_j n_i n_j p_i p_j \mathrm{Cov}(\theta_i,\theta_j)
= \sigma^2 n_i p_i \left( n_i p_i + \rho\sum_{j\not=i} n_j p_j \right)$$

The law of total covariance then gives:
$$\mathrm{Cov}(S_i,S) = n_i p_i + \sigma^2 n_i p_i \left(n_i p_i + \rho \sum_{j\neq i} n_j p_j\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I added a second question and there I tried to also calculate $Var(S)$ by applying similar ideas as yours. Are my calculations correct?